# shell script, how to port checking based on range . example: port no 10000 - 30000,

Tags: shell, unix

how do I check a port range example 1000 - 3000 is open or closed and then write it into a text file using unix shell script.

Comment: what's wrong with `nmap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question was more about how to do the range in a script:

```
seq 1000 3000
```

will print on each line numbers 1000 to 3000

So you could have in your script

```
for port in $(seq 1000 3000) ; do
   something with "$port"
done
```

Otherwise, as @jm666 rightly pointed out, it's really a job that [nmap](http://nmap.org) was built to do  (and will do probably much better than most scripts you could ever make... Or, please, contribute your improvements to the nmap team!)